# Can I connect my smartphone to my Yamaha dx230 via USB to expand the sound bank?

Tags: midi, keyboard

I do not have a good Hammond B3 sound on my Yamaha dx230 for Santana and Pink Floyd songs. I don't have a computer or midi either. I have ccx, a smartphone, and a tablet and am wondering if I can hook up to the USB at the back of the keyboard, get the sound off my smartphone, and plug it into the Yamaha.

Comment: CCx the band? Are you asking if you can sample the B3 from one of their songs and download it to your keyboard? (Otherwise, I'm not familiar with CCX....)

Comment: Also, do you mean DX230 or DGX230. I'm familiar with Yamaha's DGX line, but not DX.

Comment: (following @aaron 's first comment) Or are you trying to control a synth app with the keyboard?